# jQuery: Target all elements with val less than 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have multiple elements in the dom with a class of `.blockbadge` if the value of any `.block-badge` is 0 then I want to add a class to that element in order to style it differently.

My JS adds the class to all of these elements if anyone of them equal 0. How do I make it only affect those elements which equal zero?

**HTML**

```
<span class="block-badge">1</span>
<span class="block-badge">0</span> // this element should have the class 'zero' added
<span class="block-badge">4</span>
```

**JS**

```
var blockBadgeVal = $('.block-badge').val();

if (blockBadgeVal < 0) {
    $('.block-badge').addClass('zero');
}
```

Comment: `span` element does not have `value` property

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in the OP will not work because `$('.block-badge').html()` will return the html of the first element with class `block-badge` so in this case return string `1`, you should parse the returned value then compare it with the `0`.

You could use **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** method instead.

> **Description:** Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
$('.block-badge').filter(function(){
     return parseInt($(this).text())==0;
}).addClass('zero');
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('.block-badge').filter(function(){
     return parseInt($(this).text())==0;
}).addClass('zero');
```

```css
.zero{
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="block-badge">1</span>
<span class="block-badge">0</span>
<span class="block-badge">4</span>
```

Comment: can u explain more what filter does ?

Comment: Thanks very much. Just confused about your answer tho because the code dunder Description doesn't work but the var a=$... does work

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
   $('.block-badge').each(function(){

    if(parseInt($(this).html()) ===0){

    $(this).addClass('zero');
    }


    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery `:contains` selector for that specific markup

```
$('.block-badge:contains(0)').addClass('zero');
```

it won't work if any other elements contains a zero, like `10`, `101` etc. so if you need *only* `0`, use a filter

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/v856nous/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.text(function(index, originalText) {})` where `this` is current element within collection , `originalHtml` is current `textContent`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".block-badge").text(function(index, originalText) {
    if (originalText <= 0) {
      $(this).addClass("zero");
    }
    return originalText
  });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s2g3zpwr/3/